# How can I change options in Select with Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, material-ui

I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wN5C.png)
How to customize option and Select [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trOAN.png).
I tried to use Selector instead NativeSelector, but the menu item appears on top of the emitting element.
**I want**

1. To center 'Genre' into select.  `textAlign = 'center'` doesn't work.
2. Add scroll
3. White anchor
4. If it possible, insert a gap between select and option

```
  const [genre, setGengre] = useState(false);

  function handleChange(e) {
    setGengre(e.target.value);
  }
  const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
      backgroundColor: "#feda00",
      width: 150,
    },
  });

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl>
        <NativeSelect
          className={classes.root}
          value={genre}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <option value="false" disabled>
            Genre
          </option>
          <option value="Pop">Pop</option>
          <option value="Hip-Hop">Hip-Hop</option>
          <option value="Rock">Rock</option>
          <option value="Funk">Funk</option>
        </NativeSelect>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: what are their differences? you want to insert a gap between select and options?

Comment: I want to style the option and select like in the second picture TextAlign = 'center' doesn't work. How change anchor style?